# How do I set a value for a hidden field in a Flask form, using wtf.quick_form?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm struggling to find out how to pass values to a hidden field in a flask-wft quick form

The template to display the form is

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am defining the form like this

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms import HiddenField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    myhidden = HiddenField()
    textblock = TextAreaField('textblock', validators=[Length(min=0, max=2000)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And rendering it like this

```
form = MyForm()
... 
return render_template('form.html', title='my form', form=form)
```

I tried to give a value to

```
form.myhidden = "test value"
```

But the rendered page shows the field value as empty

Is it possible to use hidden fields in wtf.quick_form at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was too easy.

```
form = MyForm(myhidden = 'test value')
```

will set the value for the field.